# How do I find total sales of my book?

Tags: sales

Sales reports for my book from the publisher (about 2 per quarter) are grossly inconsistent with visits to the novel's Web site (about 100 per month) and people who've told me they bought a copy.  How do I find reliable data?

Answer (score 3):

Here's interesting marketing / sales data for my Tech book at amazon.
I recently paid for advertising and you can see that views of info rarely turn into actual sales.

Yes, that's right, the ad was displayed over 25K times yet only clicked 6 times and only purchased once.

[image: sales info]

So, 100 views probably doesn't even equal 1 sale.  That's how marketing works, I guess. :)